# If thumbnail image else post title

Tags: custom-post-types, functions

I have a table with results on my website and I want to display post title when featured image is missing and to don't show button when exlink is missing.

img class="logo"  - is the featured image that needs to else title

a class="exlink"  - is the link that needs to else dont display button (almost all the way down)

This is copypasted from page template:

```
    <?php 
            query_posts(array( 
                'post_type' => 'mms',
                'showposts' => -1,
                'meta_key' => 'kr',
                'orderby'=>'meta_value_num',
                'order'=>'ASC'
            ) );  
            ?>

            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
             // $image1 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ),  array(100, 100) );
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
            ?>
            <div class="mainrecord">


            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 logoimage" >
            <img class="logo" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"/>
            <h5 class="wifi"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/wifi-signal-tower(1).png';?>" alt="img"/> <?php the_field('network'); ?></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 services new">
            <h4 class="ctitle">
            <?php 
     //  $values = get_field('select_service');

     $values = get_field('select_service');
    $field = get_field_object('select_service');
    $choices = $field['choices'];
    ?>
    <ul>
    <?php 
    foreach ($choices as $value => $label) {
        ?>



   <?php 
    if (in_array($value, $values)) {
       ?>
       <?php if($value == "Data Rollover") { ?>
       <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/loading(1).png';?>" alt="img"/><?php echo $value; ?></li>
        <?php } ?> 
        <?php if($value == "Bruk i Eu") { ?>
       <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/12.png';?>" alt="img"/><?php echo $value; ?></li>
        <?php } ?> 
        <?php if($value == "Fri tale") { ?>
       <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/phone-call(1).png';?>" alt="img"/><?php echo $value; ?></li>
        <?php } ?> 
        <?php if($value == "Fri SMS/MMS") { ?>
       <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/e-mail-envelope(1).png';?>" alt="img"/><?php echo $value; ?></li>
        <?php } ?> 
        <?php if($value == "Fri-Fart") { ?>
       <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/wifi-connection-signal-symbol(1).png';?>" alt="img"/><?php echo $value; ?></li>
        <?php } ?> 

    <?php }
    else { ?>
     <?php if($value == "Data Rollover") { ?>
     <li style="color:#e0e0e0"> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/loading(1).png';?>" alt="img"/><?php echo $value; ?></li>
     <?php } ?>
     <?php if($value == "Bruk i Eu") { ?>
     <li style="color:#e0e0e0"> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/12.png';?>" alt="img"/><?php echo $value; ?></li>
     <?php } ?>
     <?php if($value == "Fri tale") { ?>
     <li style="color:#e0e0e0"> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/phone-call(1).png';?>" alt="img"/><?php echo $value; ?></li>
     <?php } ?> 
     <?php if($value == "Fri SMS/MMS") { ?>
     <li style="color:#e0e0e0"> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/e-mail-envelope(1).png';?>" alt="img"/><?php echo $value; ?></li>
     <?php } ?>
     <?php if($value == "Fri-Fart") { ?>
     <li style="color:#e0e0e0"> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/wifi-connection-signal-symbol(1).png';?>" alt="img"/><?php echo $value; ?></li>
     <?php } ?> 
<?php   }
    ?>

<?php } ?>
</ul>


            </h4>
            <p class="thgb"><?php the_field('set_mb'); ?><br>GB</p>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12 mb">
            <p><?php// the_field('set_mb'); ?> <br/>GB</p>
            </div>-->
        <!--    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12 selectany">
            <p><?php //the_field('select_any'); ?></p>
            </div>-->
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 prices">
                <div class="priceinner">
                <?php $old = get_field( "mandespris" );
                    if( $old ) {
                ?>
                <p class="pricw"><span class="newprice">kr <?php the_field('kr'); ?>,</span>-<br/><span class="oldprice"><del>kr <?php the_field('mandespris'); ?></del>,</span>-<br/>Pris/måned</p>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <p class="pricw">kr <?php the_field('kr'); ?>,-<br/>Pris/måned</p>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <p class="nomonth">
                <a class="exlink" href="<?php the_field('link'); ?>" target="_blank">Les mer </a>
                <?php $value = get_field( "no_of_month" );
                    if( $value ) {
                ?>
                <span class="">* <?php the_field('no_of_month'); ?> Måneder</span>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion_head"><span class="plusminus">+</span>Mer Informasjon</div>
            <div class="accordion_body">
            <!--<p>First Accordian Body, it will have description</p>-->
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="rowcontent">
                <p><?php the_field('row1'); ?></p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: regardless of the question, do not ever use `query_post`

Comment: regarding the qquestion itself, there is a lot of pointless code in there that should have no relevance to the title of the question. I suggest you edit the question and trim the code down to the core of the problem to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/).

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) {
    // has thumbnail, so show thumbnail
} else {
    echo the_title();
}
```

The class exlink appears to be hardcoded and there's no IF involved so I don't know what you want to compare it to.